# Show dismissed widget on top of neighboring widgets

Tags: flutter

I have a row with three widgets:

[image]

The middle widget is Dismissible. When I slide it to the right, it slides under the next widget:

[image]

How can I get it to show on top? (assuming that I don't know the size of the elements)

Here's the code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
          ),
          Dismissible(
            key: UniqueKey(),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              width: 70,
              height: 70,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Use [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

Comment: @Alok this seems difficult if I don't know in advance the size of the three elements (for example if they are dynamically loaded images)... I'll edit the question to mention this constraint.